# Migrate AngularJS from 1.2 to 1.3

Tags: angularjs

After replacing AngularJS v1.2.14 with AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.18 I get the following error:

```
[app]  [!]Object function ( elems ) {
    for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        try {
            $( elem ).triggerHandler( "remove" );
        // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8235
        } catch( e ) {}
    }
    _cleanData( elems );
} has no method '$$original'
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: 1.3 is still in beta and should not be used at production, better to use latest stable version in the 1.2 series.

Comment: I agree with @Jai, Never work with beta version.